# Why is my C# RFID code to output card UID and ATR response not working?

Tags: c#, rfid

I am an absolute beginner to the world of RFID and its applications and i took a step of writing a code that i found on YouTube to output a Card UID and also get the ATR Value but my code did not work and i have been stuck on it for a while.

The Code can be seen below.

It is written on Visual Studio 2019. And for my project template, I used the "Windows Forms App" - A project template for creating a .NET Windows Forms(WinForms)App.

RFID Reader Used - OMNIKEY 5022 Reader

The code below was written behind a "Read" Button on the form, and as I press the button its supposed to show the CARD UID and ATR Value in the textbox that I provided.

```
using System;
using PCSC;
using PCSC.Iso7816;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SCardContext ctx = new SCardContext();
                ctx.Establish(SCardScope.System);
                string[] readernames = ctx.GetReaders();
                if(readernames.Length == 1) //This gets the number of readers conected to the desktop which can be found in the READERNAMES array.
                {
                    string readername = readernames[0];//Store reader found in the readernames array
                    SCardReader RFIDReader = new SCardReader(ctx);//Create reader instance to enable connection to smart card.
                    SCardError readerError;

                    //Begin connection to the reader
                    readerError = RFIDReader.Connect(readername, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any);
                    if(readerError == SCardError.Success)//Meaning if the reader successfully connected
                    {
                        //Lets get the ATR First
                        byte[] ATR;//Variable to store the ATR value
                        readerError = RFIDReader.GetAttrib(SCardAttribute.AtrString ,out ATR);//This means that the reader connected should  send ATR response
                        if(readerError == SCardError.Success && ATR.Length > 2)
                        {
                            string RFIDdata = BitConverter.ToString(ATR ?? new byte[] { }).Replace("-", " ");
                            textBox1.Text = RFIDdata;
                        }

                        //Now to get the UID.
                        byte[] SendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //Gets UID Command
                        byte[] RecvBytes = new byte[35]; //Adequate Buffer Size
                        readerError = RFIDReader.Transmit(SendBytes, ref RecvBytes);
                        if(readerError == SCardError.Success)
                        {
                            string RFIDdata = BitConverter.ToString(RecvBytes ?? new byte[] { }).Replace("-", " ");
                            textBox2.Text = RFIDdata;
                        }

                        RFIDReader.Disconnect(SCardReaderDisposition.Reset);

                    }
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help figuring out why I did not get any response after pressing the read button.

Comment: There are lots of different versions of the card and different card readers.  Old card readers cannot read new type cards.  Most of the time the issue is with the encryption that locks the card.  Before trying c# try to open card with a file explorer in windows.  Error message will be better in windows to help solve issue.  One possibility is you didn't install the driver (or latest driver) to unlock the card.  Normally I recommend starting by unlocking card in windows.  Than read/write card in c#.  After getting read/write working than try unlock in c#.  Cards have 8/16/32/64 bit modes.

Comment: Unlocking card you need to know the size of the address and size of data.  So first unlocking in windows you can figure out the sizes which makes unlocking much easier.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your response, I looked up unlocking card in windows but I keep seeing related posts of Unlocking PC using SD Card. Can I get a link to a preferred website if possible as I am sort of confused on what you mean.@jdweng

Comment: The card will automatically get unlocked when you try to access the folders in the card with a file explorer.  If you not have driver installed (or missing a certificate with key) you will get an access error.   Once unlocked it will stay unlocked until the PC is turned off.  So once unlocked in windows a c# application should be able to read and write card.  So you can develop you application without worrying about unlocking in c#.  The hard part of code is getting the sizes of address and data correct.  So I normally read an existing file in c# and get the address and data correct.